# get parameter in OSClass

Tags: parameters, osclass

In OSClass, I need to get parameter from `item-post.php` to `ItemActions.php`. I know 2 ways, one is like, `$aItem['catId']` and another is `Params::getParam('catId')`.

But second is won't work for **file** type. Any other way to get `file type`?

Because of, I using following code,

```
$this->uploadItemResources( $aItem['photos'] , $itemId );

$this->uploadItemResources( $aItem['layout'] , $itemId );
```

Here photos are inserted correctly. But I didn't get layout value. In item-post.php my code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$someFiles = Params::getFiles('param_name');
```

In your case

```
$someFiles = Params::getFiles('photos');

$otherFiles = Params::getFiles('layout');
```

Comment: I missed " $aItem['layout'] = Params::getFiles('layout'); " in prepareData() in ItemAction.php